# Get method by its name in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I know how to get method of object in javascript (using bracket notation) but couldn't understand how to achieve the same in Typescript?

When trying to do `this[methodName]` getting error `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyWebSocket' has no index signature. [7017]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use type assertion to tell the compiler that `methodName` value is restricted so it can only be one of the method names which are declared for `this`.

For example

```
this[methodName as 'method1' | 'method2']
```

Or if you have some interface named for example `Methods` where all the methods you are going to call for `this` are declared

```
this[methodName as keyof Methods]
```

Another solution is to opt-out from typechecking by using `as any` type assertion:

```
(this as any)[methodName]
```

Comment: I.e. I cannot use any string received to get method without specifying it explicitly?

Comment: Yes you have to give it an explicit type (and maybe check it at runtime), because with the `--strict...` options you have in effect it's not considered type-safe by the compiler